# modify the _dispatcher field in the DispatcherObject by reflection to modify the properties of a DispatcherObject object across threads?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to modify the _dispatcher field in the DispatcherObject by reflection to modify the properties of a DispatcherObject object across threads?

I am a newcomer to wpf development. By observing the source code of DispatcherObject, I understand that the DispatcherObject object can only be accessed by his associated Dispatcher. In the case of cross-threading, can I modify the access permission by modifying the _dispatcher field so that the current thread can operate correctly? DispatcherObject, this problem has been bothering me for a long time.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread threadOri = Thread.CurrentThread;

            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                FieldInfo field = typeof(DispatcherObject).GetField("_dispatcher", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                DispatcherObject obj = new UIElement();

                field.SetValue(btn, obj.Dispatcher);

                try
                {
                    btn.Width = 100;
                }
                catch
                { }

                try
                {
                    btn.Height = 100;
                }
                catch
                { }

                try
                {

                    //There is an error here
                    TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
                    field.SetValue(tbx, Dispatcher.FromThread(threadOri));
                    btn.Content = tbx;

                }
                catch
                { }


                field.SetValue(btn, Dispatcher);
            });

            thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();

            //Why is there no automatic redraw?
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. If you want to update the UI from a non-UI thread then use a callback sent to the Dispatcher.

Comment: Besides that, you don't also need to (or want to) deal with threads any longer. Take a look at [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: Yes, I will, thank you for your answer, but I still want to know what happened inside. Why is it normal for me to set the height width, but I throw an exception when I set the Content property (still can successfully modify the Content , but it is not shown in the visual tree), my English is very poor, please forgive me...

Comment: Because `TextBox tbx` is created in another thread than the UI thread. The visual tree may only contain objects that were created in the same thread.

Comment: @Clemens `async` code can still block the UI thread unnecessarily if it involves a lot of heavy CPU-intensive work before yielding or if library code doesn't use `ConfigureAwait` to stop it resuming on the UI thread when there's CPU-intensive work involved (there's also buggy `async` code like `HttpClient` which performs DNS lookups in a blocking fashion (!!). If anything will take longer than 16ms (i.e. 1 frame at 60Hz) then use a background thread, even if it is `async` code.

Comment: @Clemens How am I wrong? `HttpClient` (in .NET Framework, not .NET Core) does not perform async DNS and if the DNS resolver is slow then it blocks the UI thread unnecessarily.

Comment: @Dai You can't take that as a reason for not using async/await in general. "*If anything will take longer than 16ms (i.e. 1 frame at 60Hz) then use a background thread*" doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @Clemens I'm using it as an example to argue against your claim that merely using an async API means you "don't need to" use background threads, because an async API can misbehave and it's no guarantee the UI thread won't block, whereas using a background thread does guarantee the UI thread won't block. And if a programmer inadvertently uses `.ConfigureAwait(false)` inside a UI function continuation then they'll still get wrong-thread-usage exceptions.

Comment: @Clemens My 16ms rule-of-thumb is about preventing a jittery UX because the UI thread was blocked for long enough that it couldn't complete a full Window message loop and render/paint cycle at 60Hz (for a 60fps UI), this is especially important in WPF which is rendered using DirectX and most WPF skins are visually intensive with lots of animation present: users _expect_ a smooth and fluid 60fps experience in WPF applications and running potentially slow operations on the UI thread will break that experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `Dispatcher` property of a single UI element in a visual tree does't make sense, since all elements in the tree must have the same thread affinity.

If you need to create a UI element from a background thread, the creation code must be invoked in the UI thread's Dispatcher, just as any other access to UI elements:

```
btn.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    btn.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Click Me!" };
});
```